# New Radio install

Tags: audio

I have a 2003 f150 I'm installing a new DBL din head unit, the one i'm pulling out is a single din after market head unit, I wired up the harness and the unit would not turn on, i double checked everything and have power and ground up to the  connections of the wire harness I plug it in and there's nothing, I decided to wire up the old radio I removed and now that radio has no power, I would appreciate any idea's.....Thanks!! Jay

Comment: How are you checking for 12v power?  Sure sounds like either blown fuse or hard shell push out. A push out is where an electrical connector isn’t properly seated inside a plastic hard shell connector.

Comment: @zipzit you should write this as an answer, the only other possibility is a duff unit, but given the old one now does not work your answer holds...

Comment: To OP: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!